# go_router - how to push a page over existing pages in stack (in any path)

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-go-router, gorouter

I use go_router for navigation handling in my project. I have an invoice page, and I want to show this page after payment is done over existing pages on navigation stack.

For example, if the user is in /detail/book, /profile/job, or whatever path, I want to push that invoice page over all of my route paths with a back button on it to get back to the previous page.

I tried doing this manually with Navigator 2, but I don't know how to do it with Go Router.

Comment: does `context.push` work ?

Comment: Use `context.go()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the go_router documentation
`context.go('route')` navigates to route by replacing stack of views
`context.push('route')` navigates to route by adding view to the stack which can be removed by the back button you want with `context.pop()`